# socket python library. client crashes

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I start the server, then the client, the server gets the data and the client does not get a response, crashes

## server

```
import pygame, socket, time
pygame.init()

main_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
main_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
main_socket.bind(("localhost", 10000))
main_socket.setblocking(0)
main_socket.listen(5)

players_sockets = []


while True:
    
    try:
        new_socket, addr = main_socket.accept()
        print("Connect", addr)
        new_socket.setblocking(0)
        players_sockets.append(new_socket)
    except:
        pass

    
    for i in players_sockets:
        try:
            data = i.recv(1024)
            data = data.decode()
        except:
            pass 

    for i in players_sockets:
        try:
                 i.send("server data").encode()
        except:
            players_sockets.remove(i)
            print("Disconnect")
            i.close()
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

## client

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
sock.connect(("localhost", 10000))

while True:

    sock.send("Command".encode())

    data = sock.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()

    print(data)
```

error:

```
" data = sock.recv(1024)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] The program on your host computer has broken an established connection."
```

Comment: Get rid of the bare try/excepts and see what errors you are getting.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).